FastAPI + Shopify OAuth: Route Not Found and HMAC Verification Failing
I'm developing a Shopify app using FastAPI and encountering issues with the OAuth flow. Specifically, I'm facing two problems:

Route Not Found (404 Error): The /install endpoint is returning a 404 error during testing.
HMAC Verification Failing (400 Error): The HMAC verification fails during the callback, resulting in a 400 error.

Environment:
Python 3.11.10
FastAPI
pytest 8.3.4
What I've Tried:
Verified router inclusion in main.py
Checked environment variable mocking in tests
Ensured HMAC generation logic matches Shopify's documentation
My questions basically are:
Why is the /install route returning a 404 error?
How can I resolve the HMAC verification failure?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
I've been also trying to debug this with Cursor AI (different LLMs) but several hours later I have to give up.
main.py
from app.routers import shopify

app = FastAPI()

app.include_router(shopify.router, prefix="/shopify", tags=["shopify"])

shopify.py
from fastapi import APIRouter, HTTPException
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse
import os
import secrets
import hmac
import hashlib

router = APIRouter()

SHOPIFY_API_KEY = os.getenv("SHOPIFY_API_KEY")
SHOPIFY_API_SECRET = os.getenv("SHOPIFY_API_SECRET")
REDIRECT_URI = os.getenv("SHOPIFY_REDIRECT_URI")
SCOPES = "read_products,read_orders,read_analytics"

def verify_oauth_request(params: dict, secret: str) -> bool:
    params_without_hmac = params.copy()
    params_without_hmac.pop('hmac', None)
    sorted_params = sorted((k, str(v)) for k, v in params_without_hmac.items())
    query_string = '&'.join(f"{k}={v}" for k, v in sorted_params)
    calculated_hmac = hmac.new(
        secret.encode('utf-8'),
        query_string.encode('utf-8'),
        hashlib.sha256
    ).hexdigest()
    return hmac.compare_digest(calculated_hmac, params['hmac'])

@router.get("/install")
async def install(shop: str):
    if not shop:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Shop parameter required")
    nonce = secrets.token_urlsafe(16)
    install_url = (
        f"https://{shop}/admin/oauth/authorize?"
        f"client_id={SHOPIFY_API_KEY}&"
        f"scope={SCOPES}&"
        f"redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URI}&"
        f"state={nonce}&"
        f"access_mode=offline"
    )
    return RedirectResponse(url=install_url, status_code=307)

@router.get("/callback")
async def callback(code: str, shop: str, state: str, hmac: str):
    params = {"code": code, "shop": shop, "state": state, "hmac": hmac}
    if not verify_oauth_request(params, SHOPIFY_API_SECRET):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Invalid HMAC")
    # Token exchange logic...

test_oauth.py
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from app.main import app
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

client = TestClient(app)

class TestOAuthFlow(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('app.routers.shopify.os.getenv')
    def test_install_endpoint(self, mock_getenv):
        mock_getenv.side_effect = lambda key: {
            'SHOPIFY_API_KEY': 'test_key',
            'SHOPIFY_API_SECRET': 'test_secret',
            'SHOPIFY_REDIRECT_URI': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/shopify/callback',
            'SCOPES': 'read_products,read_orders,read_inventory'
        }.get(key, None)
        shop = "test_shop.myshopify.com"
        response = client.get(f"/shopify/install?shop={shop}")
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 307)

    @patch('app.routers.shopify.requests.post')
    @patch('app.routers.shopify.os.getenv')
    def test_callback_exchange_token(self, mock_getenv, mock_post):
        mock_getenv.side_effect = lambda key: {
            'SHOPIFY_API_KEY': 'test_key',
            'SHOPIFY_API_SECRET': 'test_secret',
        }.get(key, None)
        mock_post.return_value.status_code = 200
        mock_post.return_value.json.return_value = {"access_token": "test_access_token"}
        params = {"code": "test_code", "shop": "test_shop.myshopify.com", "state": "test_state", "hmac": "test_hmac"}
        query_string = '&'.join(f"{k}={v}" for k, v in params.items())
        response = client.get(f"/shopify/callback?{query_string}")
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

